# Oracle SQL Group by and sum with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

[image]

I attached a capture of two tables:
     - the left table is a result of others "Select" query
     - the right table is the result I want from the left table

The right table can be created following the next conditions:

1. When the same `Unit` have **all positive** or **all negative**
   energy values, the result remain the same
2. When the same `Unit` have **positive and negative** energy values then:

   - Make a sum of all Energy for that `Unit`(-50+15+20 = -15) and then take the maximum of absolut value for the Energy.`e.g. max(abs(energy))=50` and take the price for that value.

I use SQL ORACLE.

I realy appreciate the help in this matter !

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb85a/12

Comment: *the maximum of absolut value for the price* for B is 16 and not 13.

Comment: @forpas max(abs(-50,15,20)) = 50 and the price for that value is 13

Comment: Now you clarified, but in the question this is not clear.

Comment: @forpas Indeed it was not clear. Now I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns desired result:

- `signs` CTE finds out whether there are positive/negative values, as well as maximum ABS energy value
- then, there's union of two selects: one that returns "original" rows (if count of distinct signs is 1), and one that returns "calculated" values, as you described

---

```
SQL> with
  2  signs as
  3    (select unit,
  4            count(distinct sign(energy)) cnt,
  5            max(abs(energy)) max_abs_ene
  6     from tab
  7     group by unit
  8    )
  9  select t.unit, t.price, t.energy
 10    from tab t join signs s on t.unit = s.unit
 11    where s.cnt = 1
 12  union all
 13  select t.unit, t2.price, sum(t.energy)
 14    from tab t join signs s on t.unit = s.unit
 15    join tab t2 on t2.unit = s.unit and abs(t2.energy) = s.max_abs_ene
 16    where s.cnt = 2
 17    group by t.unit, t2.price
 18  order by unit;

UNIT                      PRICE     ENERGY
-------------------- ---------- ----------
A                            20        -50
A                            50        -80
B                            13        -15

SQL>
```

Though, what do you expect if there was yet another "B" unit row with `energy = +50`? Then two rows would have the same `MAX(ABS(ENERGY))` value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works very well. Regarding your question, that case it never happened, and I hope it will remain like that :)

Answer (score 0):

A `union all` might be the simplest solution:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             max(energy) over (partition by unit) as max_energy,
             min(energy) over (partition by unit) as min_energy
      from t
     ) 
select unit, price, energy
from t
where max_energy > 0 and min_energy > 0 or
      max_energy < 0 and min_enery < 0
union all
select unit,
       max(price) keep (dense_rank first order by abs(energy)),
       sum(energy)
from t
where max_energy > 0 and min_energy < 0
group by unit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Do you know why I can't verify  the query in fiddle ?`http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb85a/12`.  It says: "recursive WITH clause must have column alias list"

Comment: @BOB . . . This addresses the question asked in this question.  I see no need for a recursive query.  If you have another question about that code (and the error seems self-explanatory), ask it as another question.